# Populate date into another date field

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo, struts2

I am using struts2 datetimepicker tag in my jsp page for choosing the date. I need to auto populate the date selected in date1 into date2 field. I have tried using javascript and dojo to do this, but the date is not getting auto populated. Please guide me on this.

This the code which i have tried.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sd" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    // Dojo configuration
    djConfig = {
        isDebug: false,
        bindEncoding: "UTF-8"
          ,baseRelativePath: "/WebContent/WEB-INF/dojo-release-1.7.1/dojo/"
          ,baseScriptUri: "/WebContent/WEB-INF/dojo-release-1.7.1/dojo/"
         ,parseWidgets : false
    };
</script> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/WebContent/WEB-INF/dojo-release-1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
  dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
  dojo.require("dojo.widget.Button");

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);

function populate(){
alert(ab);
}
function init()
{
var ab = dojo.widget.byId('id1');
dojo.event.connect(ab, 'onblur', 'populate')
}  
 </script>
<sd:head/>

</head>

<body>
<s:form action="resultAction.action" method="post">
<sd:datetimepicker name="date1" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" label="Select Date(yyyy-mm-dd):" id="id1" onblur="populate();"/> 
<sd:datetimepicker name="date2" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" label="Select Date(yyyy-mm-dd):" id="id2" />
<s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the code ?what is the error?

Comment: show some code that you tried

Comment: -1: ask a question please. Context would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `setValue()` method on the dojo element?

```
function populate(){
    dojo.widget.byId("id2").setValue(dojo.widget.byId("id1").getValue());
}
```

Comment: also, i would have used the `onchange` event and not `onblur`.

Comment: i have tried this, but for me the populate() function itself is not getting called.

Comment: Try making it onblur="alert('Hi');populate();" and let me know if you see the alert.

Comment: i tried to call alert('hi') but it is not working. For me the control is not going to populate() from the datepicker. If i am trying with normal textbox instead of datepicker it will work and i am able to populate value. But for datepicker the script is not working.

Comment: Try `onchange` instead of `onblur` as mentioned by @Dementic.

Comment: I have tried these events, but for datetimepicker none of them is working. Do we have any other options.

Comment: In that case, view the generated html for the element using firebug or webdeveloper plugin. Please share the html if you wish to.

Comment: i am sorry, got busy in between.